# Remove all occurances of escape sequence characters available in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping

I need to remove all escape characters occurring in a string.

Example:

```
string str = "\n \b \t \r Hello \n \b \t \r";
```

expected out put: Hello.

**Note:** Escape characters in the input are few of the them. I need to remove escape char when ever its found in the input.

I have tried with `Regex.Unescape(str)`. But I didn't get this resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. You can remove a list of special characters, but you can't tell if a certain character is an escaped character or a literal character.

Comment: You do know there are more escaped characters than that? From Mr Jon Skeet. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Comment: Yes Tony Hopkinson, I know. Thats the reason i have told "few of them" in the note section of my question. Anyways, Thanks for the link you shared

Answer (score 0):

You could try a white list regexp

```
^[\b \t \n \r]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this

```
"\\[bntr]"
```

with an empty string everywhere in your input string and you should be fine unless there are other constraints - in this case, let me know.
You might want to replace the additional whitespaces afterwards as well.

Comment: Thank you both. Both gives me the solution partly. For input, "\n \b \t \r Hello \n \b \t \r World \n \b \t \r" I get the Hello printed in one line and World in newline. Does it mean, \n didn't get removed?

Comment: @4u.Ans - it seems to work fine in regexpal.com - are you sure the input string looks like this ? Are there no additional characters ? What language are you using ?

Comment: The input is just an example. It's an input field on UI. Since I can't predict the user input, I need to take care of the input. So, I have to think of it. I'm using C#. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @4u.Ans - can you try if this helps ? `"\\r\\n|\\[bnrt]"` - new line can be \n or \r\n - it would make sense that the first regex matched both, but just in case...